# Sharepoint menu Customization

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to have a customized menu on SharePoint 2010 which looks like :

```
Menu ->

Link1    departments
Link2       department1 
Link3       department2
```

the links and departments are all in the same UL and each the first UL contain the links link is an LI .
The departments is the second UL that contain LI also I need to have them on the same level.

This my code:

```
           <li><a href="#">News</a>
                            <div class="sub">
                                <ul class="ul_border">
                                    <li><a href="#">Navigation Link</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Navigation Link</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Navigation Link</a> </li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Departments</a>
                                        <ul class="sub_ul">
                                            <li><a href="#">Department1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Department2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Department3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Department4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Department5</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Department5</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Department5</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

using the navigation of sharepoint

I need to implement this menu on sharepoint 2010 but i need to have all these links on the same level.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2011/05/06/sharepoint-2010-custom-sub-level-navigation/

Comment: It's standard practice to describe the content of the link, and if at all possible to quote the relevant section in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to SharePoint but to CSS and HTML. If I understand your correctly you need [How to Create a Horizontal Dropdown Menu with HTML, CSS and jQuery](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this by .xml file rather than ul and li elements. Code inside can be for example:

```
   <siteMap>
    <siteMapNode title="Dept1" url="/collection/" />   
    <siteMapNode title="Dept2" url="/collection/" />
    <siteMapNode title="Dept3" url="/collection/">
        <siteMapNode title="Sub_Dept3" url="/collection/site1" />    
        <siteMapNode title="Sub_Dept3" url="/collection/site2" />
    </siteMapNode>
   </siteMap>
```

Disadvantage is the fact, that you can't use same link twice. Or I don't know how without redirect pages. Google can find a lot of articles about top navigation, for example here http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2009/01/creating-two-tier-global-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

Try use it method http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-7-using-simple.html

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference.

Comment: Im using this method but the purpose is that im adding a third dynamic level but this third dynamic level is showing as a third level but what i need is that this third level will be on the second level but having it's own navigation(like it's the third level ani idea?)